# My script runs with no problems but the bot doesnt do anything in the group chat what do i do to fix my problem

Tags: python, python-3.x, bots, telegram

```
import telegram
import os
import time

def send_file_content_to_telegram(token, chat_id, file_path, file_name):
\# Initialize bot
bot = telegram.Bot(token=token)

    # Read content of the file
    with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
        file_content = file.read()
    
    # Send content to the group
    bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text=f"Content of {file_name}:\n\n{file_content}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
\# Enter your Telegram bot token here
bot_token = "token"

    # Enter the chat ID of the group you want to send messages to
    chat_id = "chat id"
    
    # Enter the directory containing the files
    directory_path = "C:\Users\heinr\OneDrive\المستندات\CCTV"
    
    while True:
        # Get a list of all files in the directory
        files = [f for f in os.listdir(directory_path) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(directory_path, f))]
    
        # Send content of each file to Telegram group
        for file_name in files:
            file_path = os.path.join(directory_path, file_name)
            send_file_content_to_telegram(bot_token, chat_id, file_path, file_name)
    
        print("Scanning folder...")
    
        # Wait for 5 seconds before scanning again
        time.sleep(5)
    
    print("Script ended.")
```

Comment: Please fix the formatting of your post